# Eliminate factors contributing less

Tags: r, data-science

There are hundreds of levels in a column and not all of them really add value - as in, about 60% of levels account for <80% (they don't occur many a times in the dataframe) and also expected to not influence the outcome. Objective is to eliminate those levels that do not contribute more than 80%. 
Could someone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Its ok to downvote - could you please add some comments so as to make amendments? thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by contributing? Do you use a statistical test? Which one? Can you give a reproductible example?

Comment: First you need to find a reasonable way to spot/specify which levels you want to exclude. You can do that based on a statistical test, or based on popularity (levels with very few rows each). Then, you should think whether you want to eliminate them (you'll eliminate whole rows as well) or recode them into another level (eg. "rest").

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple process that spots values that account for less than 80% of the dataset (rows) and groups them together using a new value. This process uses a character column and not a factor column.

```
library(dplyr)

# example dataset
dt = data.frame(type = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","c","D"),
                value = 1:8, stringsAsFactors = F)

dt

#   type value
# 1    A     1
# 2    A     2
# 3    A     3
# 4    B     4
# 5    B     5
# 6    B     6
# 7    c     7
# 8    D     8

# count number of rows for each type
dt %>% count(type)

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#    type     n
#   <chr> <int>
# 1     A     3
# 2     B     3
# 3     c     1
# 4     D     1

# add cumulative percentages
dt %>% 
  count(type) %>% 
  mutate(Prc = n/sum(n),
         CumPrc = cumsum(Prc))

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#    type     n   Prc CumPrc
#   <chr> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     A     3 0.375  0.375
# 2     B     3 0.375  0.750
# 3     c     1 0.125  0.875
# 4     D     1 0.125  1.000

# pick the types you want to group together
dt %>% 
  count(type) %>% 
  mutate(Prc = n/sum(n),
         CumPrc = cumsum(Prc)) %>%
  filter(CumPrc > 0.80) %>%
  pull(type) -> types_to_group

# group them
dt %>% mutate(type_upd = ifelse(type %in% types_to_group, "Rest", type))

#   type value type_upd
# 1    A     1        A
# 2    A     2        A
# 3    A     3        A
# 4    B     4        B
# 5    B     5        B
# 6    B     6        B
# 7    c     7     Rest
# 8    D     8     Rest
```

Comment: Thank you AntoniosK - there is of course a cognitive load in understanding the question :)